# Configure the LXC/LXD network bridge after uppgrading from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: lxc, lxd

The upgrade to 16.04 breaks the LXC/LXD network bridge configuration used in 15.10.

What changes do I need to make to get the new setup working? I want the guest to be on the same network as the host.

Comment: What configuration are you using and what error message are you getting ?

Comment: The config is too complicated and in too many places to list here. My guests are assigned IP addresses, but the network does not work. The guides have not caught up with the new release yet.

Comment: can not really help without looking at your config. Simply stating it is not working does not give sufficient information.

Comment: ok, someone else probably will

Comment: The container starts, and gets an IP address, and has network access when accessed through the host. SSH, webserver, and everything else is down.

Comment: Sounds like an upgrade gone bad. Make a new container and see if it works. Also just stating something is broken is not going to help as it is insufficient information. We need config files and this is going to be a very difficult problem to debug.

Comment: This thread reports the exact same problem with similar config to mine. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321382

Comment: I am not going to beg you for information to solve your problem. 1. Post your configuration, not a link to similar configs. 2. Try a new container with default configuration options on your current install and if that fails a new container with default configuration settings on a fresh installation or live flash drive. That information would be a start at least. Otherwise, if you do not provide the information I am needing, I am done, good luck to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the upgrade change the lxd bridge to the one used in the 15.10 config.

/etc/default/lxd-bridge

```
USE_LXD_BRIDGE="false"
LXD_BRIDGE="bridgeID"
```

In my case the network adapter name changed from eth1 to eth0 during the upgrade. If you don't get an IP address, edit the config of the container to match the interface name used in the container.

```
lxc config edit containername
```